# MySQL error 1033

Tags: mysql

With a new installed local MySQL databse we had this error message: 
Incorrect information in file: '.\xxx\tablename.frm' when using LOCK TABLES

All other tables in the database seemed OK. Since there were no important data, we erased the database and created a new one. Everything was OK.

Now, after running for a few days, the same error message shows up. Now for another table in the database. The other tables are OK, it looks like.

I know the error message means the table is corrupt, and I'm sure we can fix it. But my concern is why this happened twice, in a week. We've got about hundred similar installations, and never had corrupt tables.

Any ideas what to do, and what the cause is?

Comment: Google "mysql error 1033" you will find many web sites that explain how to deal with it.

Comment: corrupted tables. This question probably gets closed and moved to the proper network site on Stack Exchange for a solution.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! I've added some information. Maybe the question belongs somewhere else, but as a developer this was the natural place for me.

Comment: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,289705 (Changing tmpdir causes InnoDB to break)
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,606113 (error: 1033: Incorrect information in file:)
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,516299 (storage engine becomes NULL)
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,507553 (InnoDB Disabled)
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,416112 (moved database folder resulted in currupt db)

Comment: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,392066 (SQL Error: 1033, SQLState: HY000 Incorrect information in file)
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,363970 (ERROR 1033 (HY000): Incorrect information in file)
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?28,293677 (Restoration with .myd .myi & .frm files)
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,282170 (ERROR 1033 (HY000): Table './db_name/tb_name' was created with a different version of MySQL and cannot be read)
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,106192 (Error No. 1033 Incorrect information in file: 'filename')